# Removing Duplication In Ramda Function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, ramda.js

How can I remove the duplicated calls to `findIndexInO` in `compareIndexes`?

```
const a = [
  {name: 'charlie', value: 1},
  {name: 'bravo', value: 7},
  {name: 'delta', value: 12},
  {name: 'alpha', value: 19},
]

const propEqName = propEq('name');
const findIndexInO = findIndex(__, a);
const compareIndexes = comparator((from, to) => lt(findIndexInO(propEqName(from)), findIndexInO(propEqName(to))))
const sortOnIndex = sort(compareIndexes);

const decideOrder = (...args) => sortOnIndex(args);

decideOrder('delta', 'charlie'); // ['charlie', 'delta']
decideOrder('bravo', 'alpha'); // ['bravo', 'alpha']
decideOrder('alpha', 'charlie'); // ['charlie', 'alpha']
```

[REPL](http://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.24.1#?const%20a%20%3D%20%5B%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27charlie%27%2C%20value%3A%201%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27bravo%27%2C%20value%3A%207%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27delta%27%2C%20value%3A%2012%7D%2C%0A%20%20%7Bname%3A%20%27alpha%27%2C%20value%3A%2019%7D%2C%0A%5D%0A%0Aconst%20propEqName%20%3D%20propEq%28%27name%27%29%3B%0Aconst%20findIndexInO%20%3D%20findIndex%28__%2C%20a%29%3B%0Aconst%20compareIndexes%20%3D%20comparator%28%28from%2C%20to%29%20%3D%3E%20lt%28findIndexInO%28propEqName%28from%29%29%2C%20findIndexInO%28propEqName%28to%29%29%29%29%0Aconst%20sortOnIndex%20%3D%20sort%28compareIndexes%29%3B%0A%0Aconst%20decideOrder%20%3D%20%28...args%29%20%3D%3E%20sortOnIndex%28args%29%3B%0A%0AdecideOrder%28%27delta%27%2C%20%27charlie%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27charlie%27%2C%20%27delta%27%5D%0AdecideOrder%28%27bravo%27%2C%20%27alpha%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27bravo%27%2C%20%27alpha%27%5D%0AdecideOrder%28%27alpha%27%2C%20%27charlie%27%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20%5B%27charlie%27%2C%20%27alpha%27%5D%0A%0A)

Comment: Modify findIndexIn0 to memoize the results in a hash? Or even preproduce an index hash out of the array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
const order = addIndex(reduce)((ord, a, idx) => assoc(a.name, idx, ord), {}, a)
const decideOrder = unapply(sortBy(prop(__, order)))
```

? Since you're already embedding `a` in your function.  As an added benefit, you would then also be able to do this, if it matters to you:

```
decideOrder('delta', 'alpha', 'bravo') //=> ["bravo", "delta", "alpha"]
```